# PHP DateTime conversion - Conversion returning bool(false)

Tags: php, datetime, strtotime

SO,
Need help converting the string below into a valid DateTime object, so I can then convert it using strtotime (for a datetime comparison).

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#8 (1) { [0]=> string(33) "2015-07-30T12:40:10.0000000-05:00" }
```

That is what is returned from this:

```
$dtCurrentEvent = new DateTime($alarm->DateTime);
```

Then, when I attempt to do:

```
$dtCurrentEvent = strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $dtCurrentEvent));
```

I get the boolean false return value.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: So, we should imagine what `$time_other_format` contains, right?

Comment: @u_mulder - sorry, bad copy job. OP has been updated.

Comment: `$dtCurrentEvent` is an object. You can't treat it as a string.

Comment: when i do a var_dump on $alarm->DateTime it returns the following to the browser: object(SimpleXMLElement)#7 (1) { [0]=> string(33) "2015-07-30T12:40:10.0000000-05:00" }

Answer (score 0):

to have the timestamp, use the "getTimestamp" method

```
$alarm_DateTime = "2015-07-30T12:40:10.0000000-05:00";

$dtCurrentEvent = new DateTime($alarm_DateTime);

var_dump($dtCurrentEvent->getTimestamp());
```

result :

> 1438278010